# Java - Get src value from xml

Tags: java, regex, eclipse

I have this string from a xml node:

```
<p>
  <a href="http://www.windoctor.it/hardware/amd-serie-a10-7850k-3-7-ghz-4-core/">
    <img align="left" hspace="5" width="100" src="http://www.windoctor.it/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/g_21948019_001.jpg" class="alignleft wp-post-image tfe" alt="g_21948019_001" title="" />
  </a>
  Processori AMD A-Series APU l&#8217;APU più avanzata di AMD, l&#8217;AMD A10-7850K. Talmente rivoluzionaria da sfidare la definizione stessa di processore. Con 12 core di elaborazione (4 CPU + 8 GPU)3 con la scheda grafica AMD Radeon™ R7 e funzioni esclusive come la tecnologia AMD TrueAudio4 per un audio coinvolgente, è in grado di gestire Battlefield 4™ o qualsiasi altra cosa desideri. I processori AMD A10 ti permettono di: Liberare tutto… 
  <span class="read-more">
    <a href="http://www.windoctor.it/hardware/amd-serie-a10-7850k-3-7-ghz-4-core/">
      Read More &#187;
    </a>
  </span>
</p>

<p>
  The post 
  <a rel="nofollow" href="http://www.windoctor.it/hardware/amd-serie-a10-7850k-3-7-ghz-4-core/">
    AMD SERIE A10-7850K
  </a>
  appeared first on 
  <a rel="nofollow" href="http://www.windoctor.it">
    Win Doctor
  </a>
  .
</p>
```

I want to get the value in the src properties of the image tag. In C# I used `"<img.+?src=[\"'](.+?)[\"'].+?>"` in the regex function but in java it doesn't work.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Why not use a parser?

Comment: Don't use regex to parse non-regular Strings. Use a true XML parser.

Comment: Use an appropriate parser and xPath

Comment: am I the only one who sees html instead of XML there?

Comment: @m0s: nope, I now see it too ... use JSoup or some other HTML parser.

Comment: The string come from the "description" tag of a feed rss. I need the src value for the image of the article. I'll use an html parse.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels instead of commenting always the same thing "to not parse url/html with regex" why dont you give him an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could do something like this

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

public class Image{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String s = FileUtils.readFileToString(new File(
                "E:\\workspace\\XYZ\\src\\xpath.txt"));

        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(
                "(.*?)(<img)(.*?)(src=\")(.*?)(\")(.*?)(\\/>)(.*?)",
                //                       ^^^^^
                // 1     2    3     4      5   6    7    8     9
                Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.DOTALL);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
        while (m.find()) { //use while to find all images, and if for only the first one
            System.out.print(m.group(5));
        }
    }
}
```

ps. http://txt2re.com helps a lot.

Answer (score -1):

You need to escape the backslashes.

But a much better way would be to use XPath.